# MySQL - SELECT COUNT from two tables

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have these two tables:

**type**

```
TYPE_ID           TYPE
   1              Type1   
   2              Type2   
   3              Type3   
   4              Type4
```

**user_type**

```
USRTYPE_ID        TYPE_ID
    1               1
    2               1  
    3               2 
    4               4
```

What I need to do is **count** how many types are there in **user_type** table. For e.g.

`SELECT QUERY` returns:

```
 TYPE            QUANTITY
 Type1               2
 Type2               1
 Type4               4
```

Comment: Hint join ,group by and count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
select count(USRTYPE_ID) as QUANTITY, TYPE
from user_type
inner join type
on user_type.TYPE_ID = type.TYPE_ID
group by TYPE
```